# primitive roots of 17

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I what to show that if $a$ and $b$ are primitive roots modulo prime number $p$ then $ab$ is not primitive root modulo $p$.
I want to use a counter example.
let $a = 5$, $b = 7$ and $p=17$

$O(5)=16$ and $O(7)=16$ then $5$ and $7$ are primitive roots modulo $17$.
Now $ab= 35$. How can I continue?

Comment: $35\equiv 1 \pmod {17}$.  For the general problem, Hint;  a quadratic residue can never be a primitive root (why not?).

Comment: yes but we didnt reach quadratic residue in class is there any different proof?

Comment: It's going to be difficult for us to guess what you know and what you don't...I'd have thought quadratic residues were a more basic concept than primitive roots, for example.

Comment: I guess: if the two primitive  roots are $g, g^a$ with $\gcd(a,p-1)=1$ then $g\times g^a=g^{a+1}$ and $2\,|\,\gcd(a+1, p-1)$.  (that's the same argument written without reference to"quadratic residues").

Comment: if a and b are primitive roots then ab never can be a primitive root. But this cannot be shown by a counter  example.

Answer (score 2):

For any odd prime $p$ and any $a$ co-prime to $p$, we have $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv\pm 1\bmod p$. If in addition $a$ is a primitive root, we must have $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1\bmod p$.

So if $a$ and $b$ are primitive roots, what is $(ab)^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p$?